# Multiple outputs in fragment shader problem

Tags: opengl

So right now I'm trying to render my current scene to 2 textures binded on a FBO as GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT (0 & 1).

At initialization state, I attached 2 textures and call glDrawBuffers to specify 2 output locations for the shader.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_RendererID);

unsigned m_ColorBufferTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &m_ColorBufferTexture);
//...
unsigned m_AddtionalColorBufferTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &m_AdditionalColorBufferTexture);
//...

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_ColorBufferTexture, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_AdditionalColorBufferTexture, 0);

uint32_t drawBuffers[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
glDrawBuffers(2, (GLenum*)drawBuffers);
```

And in fragment shader I simply specify the

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

layout(location = 1) out vec4 pseudo_color;
```

The problem is when I try to examine whether the m_AdditionalColorBufferTexture is successfully written by rendering this texture on the screen, it failed and I got a black screen. (now the m_ColorBufferTexture can be rendered just fine.)

But if I switch the order of COLOR_ATTACHMENTs in drawBuffers, and also switch the output location of color and pseudo_color in shader, the m_AdditionalColorBufferTexture can be rendered on the screen.

It seems that glDrawBuffers is not working for me. And whichever comes first in the drawBuffers list can only receives the output from fragment shader?

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: did you check for framebuffer completeness? [`glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml)

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, i did have this status check line, and it didn't print out any error message.

Comment: You should really add a _minimal_, but also _complete_ example to reproduce the issue to your question. As it is stated currently, one can only guess. From your description, my first guess is that you either have some other `glDrawBuffer` call somewhere. or that you are not aware of the fact that the `glDrawBuffer[s]` calls affect only the currently bound FBO.